# How to produce application window recording for posting on the main site

Tags: support, images

Since this is a question-and-answer site strictly requiring a discussion to start with a question, I ask you whether you are interested in a recipe on how to record an application window and to produce a (size-)optimized animated Gif from it. I was asked this on the main site.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The suggested method works on Linux with X11.

For recording, [`FFmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/) is used, `xwininfo` for getting the window dimensions including the window handle and some Perl to process the information from `xwininfo` output.

The following script is invoked as:

```
ffmpegWinCast.sh [extra non-gif encoder opts] <my_window_recording>.(gif|mp4|mov|...)
```

After clicking an application window, recording starts. It is stopped by pressing `q` in the terminal window in which `ffmpegWinCast.sh` is running.

For posting on TeX.SX, GIF is the preferred output format.

Contents of file `ffmpegWinCast.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

#Frame rate for GIF output
FPS=12

# grab output file path from command line
outfile="${@: -1}"

function usage ()
{
  >&2 echo "Usage:   $(basename $0) [extra (non-gif) encoding options] <media file>.(gif|mp4|mov|...)" >&2
}

if [[ -z "$outfile" ]] || [[ "$outfile" = "$0" ]]
then
  usage
  exit 1
fi

outfmt=$(basename $outfile 2>/dev/null)
if [[ "$?" -ne 0 ]]
then
  usage
  exit 1
fi

SHM=/dev/shm/$outfmt
outfmt=${outfmt##*.}

# grab encoder options from command line
moreopts="${@:1:$(($#-1))}"

echo "Click the application window to be recorded" >&2
GEOM=$(xwininfo | perl -w -n -e '
  if( /Width:\s+(\d+)/ ) {
    $wd=$1;
  }
  elsif(/Height:\s+(\d+)/) {
    $ht=$1;
  }
  elsif(/Relative upper-left Y:\s+(\d+)/) {
    $whd=$1; #window handle height
  }
  elsif(/Absolute upper-left X:\s+(\d+)/) {
    $x=$1;
  }
  elsif(/Absolute upper-left Y:\s+(\d+)/) {
    $y=$1;
  }
  END {
    $ht+=$whd;
    $y-=$whd;
    print "X=$x\n";
    print "Y=$y\n";
    print "WD=$wd\n";
    print "HT=$ht\n";
  }
')

eval $GEOM

if [[ "$outfmt" = "gif" ||  "$outfmt" = "GIF" ]]
then
  #record losslessly
  [[ -f "$SHM.mkv" ]] && rm $SHM.mkv
  ffmpeg -f x11grab -r $FPS -s ${WD}x${HT} -i :0.0+${X},${Y} -vf scale="trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -preset ultrafast $SHM.mkv

  #extract global palette of 265 colours from all frames
  ffmpeg -i $SHM.mkv -vf "palettegen=stats_mode=diff" -y /dev/shm/palette.png

  #re-encode video into GIF
  ffmpeg -i $SHM.mkv -i /dev/shm/palette.png -lavfi "paletteuse=dither=sierra2" -y $outfile

  rm $SHM.mkv /dev/shm/palette.png
else
  [[ -f "$SHM" ]] && rm $SHM
  if [[ "$outfmt" = "mp4" || "$outfmt" = "MP4" ]]
  then # firefox-compatible mp4/h264
    ffmpeg -an  -f x11grab -s ${WD}x${HT} -i :0.0+${X},${Y} -vf scale="trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -level 3 $moreopts $SHM
    [[ -f "$SHM" ]] && mv $SHM $outfile
  else # other output formats
    ffmpeg -f x11grab -s ${WD}x${HT} -i :0.0+${X},${Y} -vf scale="trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" $moreopts $SHM
    [[ -f "$SHM" ]] && mv $SHM $outfile
  fi
fi
```

For GIF generation, the script executes multiple `ffmpeg` passes in order to reduce the number of colours to the GIF limit of 256. A dithering method is used for re-encoding the initially recorded video to animated GIF.

Optionally, if GIF was chosen as the output format, the file size can be further reduced using [`gifsicle`](http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/).

```
gifscicle -O3 orig.gif > optimized.gif
```

An example:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for sharing! I can definitely see such recordings being helpful in some situations, but I want to add a caveat:

Videos should only *illustrate* textual descriptions, but not *replace* them because of

- **accessibility** for users with impaired reading skills or devices that don't display images/animated gifs, and printing (or you have to provide an elaborate alt-text)
- **Googleability** -- it's fair to assume that we draw most our users (= readers) from search engines. Those unfortunately (?) aren't quite yet at the point of interpreting and indexing animated gifs.
- **unambiguousness** -- the gifs will probably mostly be used in answers; imagining a question with an animated gif of code, compiling and an error message makes me shiver ...

Answer (score 3):

Use [Licecap](https://www.cockos.com/licecap/). It provides the end user with "simple animated screen captures" and functions on all major distributions (Windows, OSX, Linux). Features include

- Record directly to .GIF or .LCF.
- Move the screen capture frame while recording.
- Pause and restart recording, with optional inserted text messages.
- Global hotkey (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>) to toggle pausing while recording
- Adjustable maximum recording frame rate, to allow throttling CPU usage.
- Basic title frame, with or without text.
- Record mouse button presses.
- Display elapsed time in the recording.

Comment: Thank you for this, didn't know licecap before.

Comment: Just visited its home page. I learned it is for Windows and OSX and doesn't run on Linux natively.